# Memory error when delete[] calls destructor

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a program that can calculate the area of a closed polygonial chain. The program seems to output the correct results until... it reaches return 0; in the main function.

The debugger reveals that upon exiting the main function, the programs calls the destructor of Vertex, on line 17 in polygon.h, and thats when everything turns into chaos! The destructor tries to free the dynamically allocated space pointed by Vertex *vertices. But it fails to do so, and is instead given a very long error message which I have pasted down below.

After trying to figure this out for some time now I'm left with no other choice than to ask for help. Can someone tell what is wrong with my program?

Thanks in advance

> Error message

```
==9715== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==9715==    at 0x400C8A: Polygon::add(Vertex const&) (Polygon.cpp:25)
==9715==    by 0x40147C: main (main.cpp:16)
==9715== 
==9715== Invalid write of size 8
==9715==    at 0x401198: Vertex::setX(int) (Vertex.h:12)
==9715==    by 0x400E07: Polygon::add(Vertex const&) (Polygon.cpp:42)
==9715==    by 0x40147C: main (main.cpp:16)
==9715==  Address 0x5959080 is 0 bytes after a block of size 64 alloc'd
==9715==    at 0x4C28147: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:348)
==9715==    by 0x400B5E: Polygon::Polygon(Vertex*, int) (Polygon.cpp:13)
==9715==    by 0x401281: main (main.cpp:8)
==9715== 
==9715== Invalid write of size 8
==9715==    at 0x4011B2: Vertex::setY(int) (Vertex.h:13)
==9715==    by 0x400E2B: Polygon::add(Vertex const&) (Polygon.cpp:43)
==9715==    by 0x40147C: main (main.cpp:16)
==9715==  Address 0x5959088 is 8 bytes after a block of size 64 alloc'd
==9715==    at 0x4C28147: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:348)
==9715==    by 0x400B5E: Polygon::Polygon(Vertex*, int) (Polygon.cpp:13)
==9715==    by 0x401281: main (main.cpp:8)
==9715== 
num:  5
==9715== Invalid read of size 8
==9715==    at 0x401174: Vertex::getY() const (Vertex.h:11)
==9715==    by 0x400ED1: Polygon::area() const (Polygon.cpp:58)
==9715==    by 0x4014C2: main (main.cpp:18)
==9715==  Address 0x5959088 is 8 bytes after a block of size 64 alloc'd
==9715==    at 0x4C28147: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:348)
==9715==    by 0x400B5E: Polygon::Polygon(Vertex*, int) (Polygon.cpp:13)
==9715==    by 0x401281: main (main.cpp:8)
==9715== 
==9715== Invalid read of size 8
==9715==    at 0x40115A: Vertex::getX() const (Vertex.h:10)
==9715==    by 0x400F08: Polygon::area() const (Polygon.cpp:59)
==9715==    by 0x4014C2: main (main.cpp:18)
==9715==  Address 0x5959080 is 0 bytes after a block of size 64 alloc'd
==9715==    at 0x4C28147: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:348)
==9715==    by 0x400B5E: Polygon::Polygon(Vertex*, int) (Polygon.cpp:13)
==9715==    by 0x401281: main (main.cpp:8)
==9715== 
==9715== Invalid read of size 8
==9715==    at 0x40115A: Vertex::getX() const (Vertex.h:10)
==9715==    by 0x400F90: Polygon::area() const (Polygon.cpp:63)
==9715==    by 0x4014C2: main (main.cpp:18)
==9715==  Address 0x5959080 is 0 bytes after a block of size 64 alloc'd
==9715==    at 0x4C28147: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:348)
==9715==    by 0x400B5E: Polygon::Polygon(Vertex*, int) (Polygon.cpp:13)
==9715==    by 0x401281: main (main.cpp:8)
==9715== 
==9715== Invalid read of size 8
==9715==    at 0x401174: Vertex::getY() const (Vertex.h:11)
==9715==    by 0x400FED: Polygon::area() const (Polygon.cpp:64)
==9715==    by 0x4014C2: main (main.cpp:18)
==9715==  Address 0x5959088 is 8 bytes after a block of size 64 alloc'd
==9715==    at 0x4C28147: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:348)
==9715==    by 0x400B5E: Polygon::Polygon(Vertex*, int) (Polygon.cpp:13)
==9715==    by 0x401281: main (main.cpp:8)
==9715== 
area:  39
minx: -1
trianglearea: 4.5
==9715== 
==9715== HEAP SUMMARY:
==9715==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9715==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 4 frees, 176 bytes allocated
==9715== 
==9715== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==9715== 
==9715== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==9715== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==9715== ERROR SUMMARY: 7 errors from 7 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
```

> /* main.cpp */

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Polygon.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
  Vertex varr[] = { Vertex(0,0), Vertex(6,0),
                    Vertex(6,6), Vertex(0,6) };
  Polygon pol( varr, 4 );
  cout << "num:  " <<  pol.numVertices() << endl;
  cout << "area:  " <<  pol.area() << endl;
  cout << "minx: " <<  pol.minX() << endl;
  cout << "maxx: " <<  pol.maxX() << endl;
  cout << "miny: " <<  pol.minY() << endl;
  cout << "maxy: " <<  pol.maxY() << endl;

  pol.add( Vertex(-1,3) );
  cout << "num:  " <<  pol.numVertices() << endl;
  cout << "area:  " <<  pol.area() << endl;
  cout << "minx: " <<  pol.minX() << endl;

  Polygon pol1;
  pol1.add( Vertex(0,0) );
  pol1.add( Vertex(3,3) );
  pol1.add( Vertex(3,0) );

  cout << "trianglearea: " << pol1.area() << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

> /* Vertex.cpp */

```
#include "Vertex.h"

Vertex::Vertex(int newx, int newy) {
  x = newx;
  y = newy;
}
```

> /* Vertex.h */

```
#ifndef VERTEX_H
#define VERTEX_H

class Vertex {
 private:
  double x, y;
 public:
  Vertex() {x = 0; y = 0;};
  Vertex(int newx, int newy);
  double getX() const { return x; }
  double getY() const { return y; }
  void setX(const int newx) { x = newx; }
    void setY(const int newy) { y = newy; }
};
```

> /* Polygon.cpp */

```
#include "Polygon.h"
#include <cmath> // For abs

// Constructor sets array of v to be the vertices of polygon
Polygon::Polygon( Vertex * const v, const int newSize ) : size(newSize) {

  // Set first element to min and max
  minx = maxx = (v[0]).getX();
  miny = maxy = (v[0]).getY();

  // Add vertices and set min/max
  int x, y;
  vertices = new Vertex[size];
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    x = v[i].getX();
    y = v[i].getY();
    (vertices[i]).setX(x);
    (vertices[i]).setY(y);
    if (i > 0)
      setMinMax(x, y);
  }
}

/* Add a single vertex */
void Polygon::add( const Vertex& v ) {
  if (size == maxSize) {
    maxSize *= 2;
    Vertex * tempPointer = new Vertex[maxSize];

    // Copy elements of previous vertice array to new one
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      (tempPointer[i]).setX((vertices[i]).getX());
      (tempPointer[i]).setY((vertices[i]).getY());
    }

    delete [] vertices;
    vertices = tempPointer;
    tempPointer = 0;
  }

  // Add single vertex to the end of vertices array
  int x = v.getX();
  int y = v.getY();
  (vertices[size]).setX(x);
  (vertices[size]).setY(y);
  setMinMax(x, y);
  size++;
}

/* Calculate area using formula on http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygonArea.html */
double Polygon::area() const {
  double area = 0, term1, term2;

  // Area must be 0 if nbr of vertices is < 3
  if (size < 3) {
    return area;
  }

   // Sum initial terms in formula
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < size-1; i++) {
    term1 = ( vertices[i].getX() * vertices[i+1].getY() ) / 2;
    term2 = ( vertices[i+1].getX() * vertices[i].getY() ) / 2;
    area += (term1 - term2);
  }

  // Sum last term in formula
  term1 = (vertices[i].getX() * vertices[0].getY()) / 2;
  term2 = (vertices[0].getX() * vertices[i].getY()) / 2;
  area += (term1 - term2);
  return fabs(area);
}

void Polygon::setMinMax(const int x, const int y) {
  if (size == 0) {
    minx = maxx = x;
    miny = maxy = y;
  }
  else {
    if (x < minx) { minx = x; }
    if (x > maxx) { maxx = x; }
    if (y < miny) { miny = y; }
    if (y > maxy) { maxy = y; }
  }
}

    #endif /* VERTEX_H */
```

> /* Polygon.h */

```
#ifndef POLYGON_H
#define POLYGON_H

#include "Vertex.h"

class Polygon {
 private:
  int size, maxSize;
  Vertex * vertices;
  double minx, miny, maxx, maxy;
  void setMinMax(const int x, const int y);
 public:
 Polygon() : size(0), maxSize(1), vertices(new Vertex[1]) {}
  Polygon( Vertex * const v, const int newSize );
  ~Polygon() { delete [] vertices; }
  void add( const Vertex& v );
  double area() const;
  double minX() const { return minx; }
  double minY() const { return miny; }
  double maxX() const { return maxx; }
  double maxY() const { return maxy; }
  int numVertices() const { return size; }
};

#endif /* POLYGON_H */
```

Comment: The solution is to get out of using pointers and just use `std::vector<Vertex>`.  Otherwise, your Polygon() class needs a user defined copy constructor and assignment operator, plus needs to be thoroughly debugged to ensure you're using the pointers correctly.  So it's your choice -- either go the easy fix, or the more involved fix.

Comment: It seems that you don't initialize `maxSize` when you create a `Polygon` with an array. So when you add a new `Vertex` to the `Polygon` `maxSize` has a wrong value...

Comment: Your `maxSize` member is uninitialized. All else flows from that.

Comment: Copy constructor and assignment operator, I haven't thought about that, good idea. But there must be a solution without using them as well? I think I'm pretty close to a solution, it's just that I'm new to C++ and can't see what I'm doing wrong. What do you think, would calling delete[] on a dynamically allocated array produce this type of error?

Comment: @user1497133 Right now, without the assignment op and copy constructor, the following program produces undefined behavior: `{Polygon p1; Polygon p2; p2 = p1;}`  The reason why is that `delete` will be called twice on the same pointer value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error stems from not initializing `maxSize` during the construction of your `Polygon` class that takes an array:

```
Polygon::Polygon( Vertex * const v, const int newSize ) : 
                  size(newSize), maxSize(newSize)
```

There are other issues with your code that you should address.

1. When you call `Polygon::add`, you prematurely increase `maxSize` by multiplying by 2, but you haven't issued a call to `new[]` to allocate the memory.  If `new[]` throws an exception, you've messed up your `maxSize` variable.  To overcome this, only change your member variables after you have allocated the memory successfully (and also, after you've cleared the hurdle of calling any `throwable` functions successfully).
2. You should provide an assignment operator and copy constructor.  If you want to make your `Polygon` object have the correct copy semantics, these functions should be implemented.  Read up about the [Rule of 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29) (and [Rule of 5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29), and [Rule of 0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29)).

Comment: You guys at Stackoverflow are so competent! I don't know how many hours I've been sitting with this. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @user1497133 - One other issue is that you're mixing up `double` and `int` for your vertices.  You pass `int` values when you initialize, but your vertex values are actually doubles.